# What happens at end of maha pralay (end of Brahma's lifespan)? Does a new yuga start right after with new Brahma? How is this different from pralay?

Tags: hanuman, brahma, yuga, pralaya

It was written in Ramayan that Hanumanji got boon that he will be the next Brahma and that is why he is waiting on Earth (Chiranjeevi) till this era ends.
Also as I understand this is 51st year (out of 100) of the current Brahma after which there will be maha pralay.  Each day of Brahma there is creation and each night there is destruction or pralay.